# can I use a fdf file to digitally sign a file

Tags: .net, security, itext, pdf-generation, digital-signature

I've got a request to sign a pdf file with an fdf file using .net and I cannot find any information on how to start or even if it's possible.

To my understanding a fdf file, it's just a collection of values not a certificate
like also explained here https://docs.appligent.com/fdfmerge/fdfmerge-form-data-format/

> An FDF file is a plain text file that contains a list of form fields and their values. Although we’ll show you how to create one by hand, most often FDF files are software generated. These are some of the more common methods to create FDF files:

> Use Adobe Acrobat to export forms data directly to a file.

I can use a pfx file to sign a pdf but I've never heard about a fdf file

I would need some help on this topic

Comment: FDF files can also be used to exchange X.509 certificates (try to export some identity from Acrobat, FDF will be one of the format choices). The person who asked you to _sign a pdf file with an fdf file_  may have thought they can send you such an FDF and you can use the data in that FDF file to sign. Unfortunately, though, I've only seen the public certificate to be sent via FDF, not the private key. If indeed this FDF use is what your question is about, therefore, you most likely cannot sign a PDF with just that FDF.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PDF Signature field.
[image]

You can copy the file here (note these are just *Proofs Of Concept* your templates will be bigger)

```
%PDF-1.2
1 0 obj <</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/AcroForm 3 0 R>> endobj
2 0 obj <</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]>> endobj
3 0 obj <</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 596 842]/Annots[4 0 R]/Contents 7 0 R
/Resources<</Font<</F1<</BaseFont/Helvetica/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/Name/F1/Subtype/Type1/Type/Font>>>>>>>> endobj
5 0 obj <</Fields[4 0 R]/SigFlags 1>> endobj
4 0 obj <</AP<</N 6 0 R>>/F 4/FT/Sig/MK<<>>/P 3 0 R/Rect[106 801 256 833]/Subtype/Widget/T(Signature1)/Type/Annot>> endobj

%       Here is the space for the digital signature field
6 0 obj <</BBox[0 0 150 32]/Length 0/Resources<<>>/Subtype/Form/Type/XObject>>
stream
endstream
endobj

%      Here are the Page contents just a line and text as graphics around the signature field
7 0 obj <</Length 107>>
stream
q 1 J 1 w 50 800 m 250 800 l .5 .5 .5 RG S
0 0 1 rg BT /F1 12 Tf 1 0 0 1 50 802 Tm (Signature) Tj ET Q
endstream
endobj

xref
trailer <</Root 1 0 R>>
%%EOF
```

here is the FDF (Forms Data File) needed for digital signing for Mr Squiggle.

```
%FDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<<
/FDF << /F (unsignedproforma.pdf)
/Fields [<</T (Signature1)>>]
/UF (unsignedproforma.pdf) >>
/Type /Catalog
>>
endobj
trailer
<< /Root 1 0 R >>
%%EOF
```

So Mr Squiggle sends the FDF to an FDF application like Tracker PDFXedit (or Acrobat) where it loads the PDF with the field activated, so they can add their personal Digital Signature with remote added timestamp. On manually saving to new file the signature has been added for use in other readers.
[image]
[image]

**The key point to note is the signature must be applied after the FDF edits the PDF so that the signing THEN will show there are no further changes AFTER that point in file history. (thus the signature cannot be inside the FDF)**

So the graphics and Personal Signing file will be applied by the local system Here is one using Acrobats signing plug-in (See how the style is different and logo in the watermark will be from the Plug-in, before encryption.)

[image]

So that does not explain how an FDF can be used for signing and we need to consider it as a WetSignature not a PKS one

Wet (Rubber Stamped Image) Signature PDF

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj <</AcroForm 2 0 R/Pages 3 0 R/Type/Catalog>> endobj
2 0 obj <</Annots[4 0 R]/Contents 5 0 R/DR<</Font<</Helv 6 0 R>>>>/Fields[4 0 R]/MediaBox[0 0 596 842]/Parent 3 0 R
/Resources<</Font<</F0<</BaseFont/Helvetica/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/Name/F1/Subtype/Type1/Type/Font>>>>>>/SigFlags 3/Type/Page>> endobj
3 0 obj <</Count 1/Kids[2 0 R]/Type/Pages>> endobj
4 0 obj <</AP<</N 7 0 R>>/BS<</W 0>>/DA(0 g /Helv 11 Tf)/DV(Enter full name of above)/F 4/FT/Tx/M(D:2023)/MK<</BC[0 0 0]>>
/P 2 0 R/Rect[106 780 256 799]/Subtype/Widget/T(Signed)/TU(Signed by)/Type/Annot/V(Enter full name of above)>> endobj
5 0 obj <</Length 107>> stream
q 1 J 1 w 50 800 m 250 800 l .5 .5 .5 RG S
0 0 1 rg BT /F0 12 Tf 1 0 0 1 50 802 Tm (Signature) Tj ET Q
endstream
endobj
6 0 obj <</BaseFont/Helvetica/Subtype/Type1/Type/Font>> endobj
7 0 obj <</BBox[0 0 150 18]/Type/XObject/Length 113/Resources<</Font<</Helv 6 0 R>>>>/Subtype/Form>>
stream
/Tx BMC q 0 0 150 18 re W n BT 0 g 0 Tc 0 Tw 100 Tz 0 Tr/Helv 11 Tf 0 5 Td (Enter full name of above)Tj ET Q EMC
endstream
endobj

xref
trailer <</Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
%%EOF
```

FDF for Mr Squiggle

```
%FDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj << /FDF << /Annots [2 0 R] /F (asignedproforma2.pdf) /Fields [<< /T (Signed) /V (Mr I. Squiggle \(AKA Ink SQuId\))
>>] /UF (asignedproforma2.pdf) >> /Type /Catalog >> endobj
2 0 obj << /AP << /N 3 0 R >> /C [1 0 0] /CreationDate (D:2023) /F 4 /IT /Stamp /M (D:2023) /Name /WetSign
/NM (12345678-1234-1234-0123456789abcdef) /Page 0 /Rect [106 801 256 833] /Subj (Stamp) /Subtype /Stamp /T (TBA) /Type /Annot >> endobj
3 0 obj << /BBox [0 0 150 36] /Length 30 /Resources << /XObject << /Im0 4 0 R >> >> /Subtype /Form /Type /XObject >>
stream
q 150 0 0 36 0 0 cm /Im0 Do Q
endstream
endobj
4 0 obj << /BitsPerComponent 1 /ColorSpace /DeviceGray /Height 30 /Length 570 /Subtype /Image /Width 150 >>
stream
ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿãÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÁü?ÿÿðÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ xÿÿÀÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿü  ÿÿ€ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿø  ÿÿ  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿð  ÿü  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿà ÿø ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿà ÿððÿÇÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿàÿþÿðþ ÿƒÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿàÿþÿà?ÿ€ÿƒÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿàÿþÿÀÿàƒÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿàÿÿÿÀÿÿàƒÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿàÿÿÿÁÿÿÀÿÁÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿàÿÿÿÁÿÿ€ÿÁÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿðÿÿÁÿþÿÁÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿðÿÿÁÿøÿÁÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿðÿÿÿÁÿàÿÁÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿàÿÿÿÀÿ€ÿÁÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ€ÿÿÿÿà~ ?ÿÀÿÿÿÿÿÿÿþ ÿÿÿÿàp ÿÿàÿÿÿÿÿÿÿàÿÿÿÿð ÿÿàÿÿÿÿÿÿü ÿÿÿÿø ÿÿàÿÿÿÿÿÿø ÿÿÿÿø ?ÿÿàÿÿÿÿÿÿø ?ÿÿÿÿà ÿÿÿñÿÿÿÿÿÿøÿÿÿÿÿÀÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿüÿÿÿÿÿÀÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÀÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿãÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
endstream
endobj
trailer
<<
/Root 1 0 R
>>
%%EOF
```

Result
[image]

So all you do is double click the FDF (or call it via your program) and Adobe Reader will sign your expense sheet or cheques for you.

[image]

### So in summary

By using FDF multiple users can all apply their signatures as legal stamps, on as many pages as required, then the "Final Document" can be signed exactly the same as any other.

[image]
[image]